# Trouble with Cassandra and ConsistencyLevel (Redundancy)

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra

So, I am been playing with Cassandra, and have setup a cluster with three nodes.  I am trying to figure out how redundancy works with ConsistencyLevels.  Currently, I am writing data with ConsistenyLevel.ALL and am reading data with ConsistencyLevel.ONE.  From what I have been reading, this seems to make sense.  I have three Cassandra nodes, and I want to write to all three of them.  I only care about reading from one of them, so I will take the first response.  To test this, I have written a bunch of data (again, with ConsistencyLevel.ALL).  I then kill one of my nodes (not the "seed" or "listen_address" machine).

When I then try to read, I expect, maybe after some delay, to get my data back.  Initially, I get a TimeoutException... which I expect.  This is what one gets when Cassandra is trying to deal with an unexpected node loss, right?   After about 20 seconds, I try again, and now am getting an UnavailableException, which is described as "Not all the replicas required could be created and/or read".

Well, I don't care about all the replicas... just one (as in ConsistencyLevel.ONE on my get statement), right?

Am I missing the ConsistencyLevel point here?  How can I configure this to still get my information if a node dies?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have Replication Factor (RF) set to 1, meaning only one node holds any given row.  Thus, when you take a node down, no matter what consistency level you use, you won't be able to read or write 1/3 of your data.  Your expectations match what should happen with RF = 3.

Comment: You are right!  I did not have my replication factor set at the keyspace level, which is where I guess I have to set it.  I thought the reads and writes individually handled how data was replicated.  I upated my keyspace, and it seems to be work fine now.  Thanks!!